# 2-sum problem, "addition" of lists version

Tags: algorithm

The problem I'm working on goes like this :

I have a list of lists and a target list. I want to see if the merger of **any** two lists is equivalent in terms of elements (and their count) to the target list.

The way I'm currently doing this involves an `O(n^2)` traversal, where I merge all possible pairs of lists and then compare their element frequency map to the element frequency map of the target.

However, this problem reminds me of the `2-sum` problem where we're supposed to find two elements in an array that sum to a specific target element. This problem can be solved in `O(n)` time, but I'm not sure how to translate this approach to my original problem.

In terms of specification, I have the possibility of building my list of lists however I want, in the sense that I can keep, say, a hash of every list instead of the list itself.

Is there maybe some hashing trick or a variation of the `2-sum` problem that can make my approach faster with respect to the original problem?

Comment: can you add example of your problem?

Comment: how many lists, how big are the numbers, how many elements in total, how many elements in each list? An efficient solution will depend on these factors

Comment: that's perfectly right juvian, unfortunately this problem is part of an interview question that's too long to post here, I don't have any other details; but I'm wondering if there's an approach that would avoid checking all pairs, I'm not particularly concerned with the overall effect other variables might have on such on approach

Comment: There are many ways where in most cases you would avoid checking all pairs, but they always have a worse case where they do. A simple one is only try to merge lists whose sum is equal to your target list sum.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense, I was looking for a more aggressive pruning scheme, like in the case of the original 2-sum problem

Comment: Any pruning scheme you can think of will have a worse case of checking all pairs

Comment: A more advanced example: calculate sum of elements, length of list, min number, max number, xor of all numbers. Create a hash out of these values. Then for each list, only check against the lists that have the corresponding hash of the missing stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can use `2-sum` technique and hashing to solve this problem more efficiently. Procedure is given below:

```
Sort the elements of each list // Here, purpose of the sort is to overcome different odering of element in the list
Sort the elements target list

listHashMap to keep the list

for each list L {

    If target list contains L {
        M = target list - L // M contains remaining element of target list
        sort this M
        if listHashMap contains M {
            L,M is your answer
        }
    }

   insert L in your listHashMap

}
```